# 1с доступ к элементу

Tags: 1с

Надо кое-что подправить на одной форме. В справочниках есть управление складами. При редактировании или создании склада открывается форма: ФормаЭлемента. Там я создал кнопку и текстовое поле. На кнопку сделал обработчик нажатия. После нажатия в текстовом поле должно написаться сообщение.

> Полный путь к форме:
> Справочники-Склады-Формы-ФормаЭлемента.

Забыл вопрос задать. ) Как добраться до этого текстового поля, чтобы задать ему какой-то текст? Текстовое поле пусть будет называться: МоёТекстовоеПоле.

Comment: А текст должен быть постоянным или он будет зависеть от каких-то условий, событий?

Comment: А это принципиально меняет путь, по которому доходят до поля?

Comment: Форма.МоёТекстовоеПоле="тут твой текст"

Comment: К форме так просто обратиться нельзя тоже. Если бы я знал, как это сделать, не спрашивал бы. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обработчике события можно написать:

> ЭлементыФормы.МоёТекстовоеПоле.Значение
> = "сообщение";

если МоёТекстовоеПоле - это элемент управления, а если реквизит формы, связанный с элементом управления, тогда:

> МоёТекстовоеПоле = "сообщение";

Answer (score 1):

> ЭлементыФормы.МоёТекстовоеПоле.Значение = "сообщение"

Считаю, это некорректно. Как минимум по причине: попытался выполнить предложенный код, в результате получил ошибку:

> {Форма.Форма(4)}: Поле объекта не обнаружено (значение)
>     ЭлементыФормы.ПолеТекстовогоДокумента.значение = "11111";

Обстоятельства. Создал внешнюю обработку. На форме внешней обработки разместил поле текстового документа. Код по кнопке выполнить:

```
Процедура КнопкаВыполнитьНажатие(Кнопка)
    ЭлементыФормы.ПолеТекстовогоДокумента.значение = "11111";
КонецПроцедуры
```

Для того, чтоб в текстовое поле (поле текстового документа) вывести текст необходимо использовать метод этого текстового поля "УстановитьТекст(Текст)". Например:

```
Процедура КнопкаВыполнитьНажатие(Кнопка)
    ЭлементыФормы.ПолеТекстовогоДокумента.УстановитьТекст("11111");
КонецПроцедуры
```

Если же автор вопроса под текстовым полем имел ввиду просто поле ввода, тип значения переменной которого равен "Строка" тогда:

1) Не рекомендую обращаться к значению поля ввода через элементы формы, т.е. так:

```
ЭлементыФормы.МоёТекстовоеПоле.Значение
```

2) При создании поля ввода автоматичсески создается реквизит формы, который содержит его значение. Вот как раз текст, который надо присвоить, и надо присваивать этой переменной:

Обстоятельства. Есть поле ввода: Имя поля ввода:"ПВМоёТекстовоеПоле", Имя реквизита формы(Данные):"РеквизитПВМоёТекстовоеПоле". Тип реквизита РеквизитПВМоёТекстовоеПоле - Строка.
При этих обстоятельствах код для присвоения этому полю ввода текста будет такой:

```
 Процедура КнопкаВыполнитьНажатие(Кнопка)
     РеквизитПВМоёТекстовоеПоле = "1111";
 КонецПроцедуры
```

Проверено на платформе 1С v8.1.14.72